# Can we count the number of triangles in the figure with combination methods?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, combinations, puzzle

How many triangle can you find in following picture?

[image]

Solution: check picture solution,

[image]

But can we solve this problem with combination methods?

Comment: Please read [this post](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960/290189) and the others there for information on writing a good question for this site. In particular, people will be more willing to help if you [edit] your question to include some motivation, and an explanation of your own attempts.

Comment: I would rotate the triangle so that one of the "bottom" corners is at the "top" so you have no other line parallel to the base. Then work down the possible "top" corners of the triangle. If you have two downward lines from the "top" point, each transversal contributes one triangle. Three downward lines gives three triangles for each transversal. But it is really just a question of systematic counting.

Answer (score 0):

$n$ lines emanating from a common point and crossing one or two other lines define $\binom n2$ triangles. You see such a configuration four times.

Comment: So how we have $24$ triangles with your solution ?